# Jquery reset html to default with multiple elements in a variable

Tags: jquery

I have multiple form elements which change corresponding html content on input. I need to reset the html of these elements to the default when the form field is cleared, but it is only using the html value of the first element in my variable. So all elements will end up with "Original text 1" instead of the specific text for that element (1,2,3 etc). I'm not sure how to do this with an array if this is the right way to go? Any help is much appreciated. [JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/ez8q4m3k/)

```
<form>                     
    <input type="text" value="" name="one" id="one" /> 
    <input type="text" value="" name="two" id="two" /> 
    <textarea name="three" id="three"></textarea> 
</form>

<div id="myDiv">
    <h2 class="one">Original text 1</h2>
    <p class="two">Original text 2</p>
    <span class="three">Original text 3</span>
</div>

var defaultVal = $("h2.one,p.two,span.three").html();

$("input, textarea").on('input', function(){
    var inputId = $(this).attr('id');
    var inputVal = $(this).val();

    if(!$.trim(this.value).length){ 
        $("#myDiv").find(('.'+inputId)).html(defaultVal);
    } else {
        $("#myDiv").find(('.'+inputId)).html(inputVal);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/sLzfL36s/)

**JS**

```
$("h2.one,p.two,span.three").each(function () {
    $this = $(this);
    $this.data("orig-text", $this.html());
});

$("input, textarea").on('input', function () {
    $this = $(this);
    var inputId = $this.attr('id');
    var inputVal = $this.val();

    $myDivText = $("#myDiv").find(('.' + inputId));

    if (!$.trim(this.value).length) {
        $myDivText.html($myDivText.data("orig-text"));
    } else {
        $myDivText.html(inputVal);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using [`data`](http://api.jquery.com/data)

```
var elems = $("h2.one,p.two,span.three");
elems.each(function () {
    $(this).data('reset-text', $(this).html());
});
(...) // Code
$('button').click(function () {
    elems.each(function (_,e) {
        $(e).html($(e).data('reset-text'));
    });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ez8q4m3k/1/)

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/ez8q4m3k/2/

```
  var defaultVal =[];
  $("#myDiv").find('*').each(function (){
        defaultVal[$(this).attr('class')]=$(this).text()
    })    
$("input, textarea").on('input', function(){
    var inputId = $(this).attr('id');
    var inputVal = $(this).val();
    if(!$.trim(this.value).length){ 
        $("#myDiv").find(('.'+inputId)).html(defaultVal[inputId]);
    } else {
        $("#myDiv").find(('.'+inputId)).html(inputVal);
    }
});
```